# python social auth: Google login Error: invalid_client

Tags: python, django, google-oauth, python-social-auth

I'm using python social auth to implement google login on my app. But I get the following error

```
Error: invalid_client
The OAuth client was not found.
```

I've tried adding a product name same as my project name and email address. But I still get this error

My redirect uri in google developer console:

```
 http://localhost:8000/complete/google-oauth2/
```

login.html

```
a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'google-oauth2' %}?next={{ index }}"> | Login with Google</a>
```

settings.py

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
    'social.backends.twitter.TwitterOAuth',
    'social.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH_KEY = ''

SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH_SECRET = ''
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Proper names for the variables in the `settings` file must be:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = ''
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = ''
```